# cycle2 is producing disorderly HTML -- is my data-cycle-slides value correct?

Tags: php, cycle2

I've used cycle2 a number of times, but am trying to do something a little different with HTML than what I normally would do.  Please see my code below.  Am I doing the right thing with the "data-cycle-slides" value?

```
<div class="cycle-slideshow"
  data-cycle-fx="scrollHorz"
  data-cycle-speed="700"
  data-cycle-timeout="3600"
  data-cycle-slides="> section > div.is-left">

  <section id="is-top">

    <?php foreach ($array as $key => $value) { ?>

      <div class="is-left ic">
        <div class="in">
          <!-- more html -->
        </div>
      </div>

    <?php } ?>

    <div id="other-stuff">
      <p>yo!</p>
    </div>

    <div id="more-stuff">
      <p>hey!</p>
    </div>

  </section>

</div>
```

It looks ok to me, and when I view the page source, nothing seems amiss.  But when I have a look in Firebug or the Firefox developer tools, things appear to be out of order.  If there are two items in the array, I see something like this...

```
<div class="cycle-slideshow" data-cycle-fx="scrollHorz" <!-- et cetera -- >>

<div class="is-left ic">
  <div class="in">
    <!-- more html -->
  </div>
</div>

<section id="is-top">

  <div id="other-stuff">
    <p>yo!</p>
  </div>

  <div id="more-stuff">
    <p>hey!</p>
  </div>

</section>

<div class="is-left ic">
  <div class="in">
    <!-- more html -->
  </div>
</div>

<div class="is-left ic">
  <div class="in">
    <!-- more html -->
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Note that items that should appear inside of #is-top are appearing outside of that section.  Also, there are somehow three .is-left items in firebug, when there should be two.

I don't know if this is a case where firebug is making a mistake and causing me some confusion, or if I'm taking the wrong approach with cycle2.

Comment: Did you try to inspect the elements using other developer tools? Note that [Firebug's development is discontinued](https://getfirebug.com). So, if it's a bug in Firebug, it won't get fixed anymore.

Comment: I am seeing the same result (the second code sample in my original post) in Firefox's built-in developer tools.

Comment: Ok, so the problem is obviously unrelated to Firebug. Therefore I've changed your question accordingly. I am wondering, though, whether this is really a cycle2 issue or rather related to PHP. Therefore, can you check how the network response for this piece of code looks like (within Firebug's *Net* panel or the Firefox DevTools' *Network* panel.)

Comment: Thanks Sebastian, but I don't know what you mean when you say to check how the network response looks.  Do you need me to paste something here?

Comment: You should add a screenshot or explain what you see when you open the related network request within the *Net* or *Network* panel. In Firebug you also have the possibility to [search within the response bodies](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Net_Panel#Search), which makes it easier to find the sources. E.g. you can search for `cycle-slideshow`.